# QUERY_ID_INVALID - Telegram inline bot

Tags: php

Olá

Estou criando um bot inline para Telegram, mas sempre me deparo com o erro QUERY_ID_INVALID. Não sei onde estou errando...

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$dados = json_decode($json,true);
$id_query = $dados['inline_query']['id'];

 $resultados_inline[] = [
                        'type'  => 'article',
                        'id'    => "1",
                        'title' => "Test",
                        'message_text' => "test",
                    ];

  $post[] = [
    'inline_query_id' => $id_query,
    'results'   => serialize($resultados_inline),           
];

  $context_options = array(
'http' => array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header'=> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
        . "Content-Length: " . strlen($post) . "\r\n",
    'content' => $post
    )
);

file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $api_telegram . "/answerInlineQuery",NULL,$context);
```

O código roda bem, mas o Telegram sempre me retorna aquele erro. Poderiam me auxiliar?

Grato

Answer (score 1):

Eu pesquisei por esse problema e obtive a seguinte resposta do Bot Support:

> "inline queries require a fast answer, if the answer is delayed, you may get that error and the answer won't be valid. I suggest you to answer faster to them in order to make them work."

Resumindo, o meu problema é que eu estava usando o debug mode e ele demorava a responder e a API retornava esse erro. Eu tbm tive que mudar meu projeto, pois essa resposta requere ser extremamente rápidas.